# How to organise customers according to their membership level

Tags: excel

In my excel sheet I got 700 data, with Customer name, code, membership level, email and phone number. I want to group the customers according to their membership level ex. gold customers, silver customers and bronze customers.

Thanks

Comment: You want a Pivot Table.

Comment: Do a sort using a custom sort order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Data Tab select group to create groups after sorting accordingly.

Shortcut `Alt+A+G+G`

Comment: Select header row pres Alt then D + F+F sort alphabetically.